# Finding the area of a parallelogram given the length of its diagonals and their intersection angle

Tags: trigonometry, area, quadrilateral

> The diagonals of a parallelogram have lengths of $15.6 \text{cm}$ and $17.2 \text{cm}$. They intersect at an angle of $120$. Find the area of the parallelogram.

The part I find most confusing is the intersection angle. I thought diagonals intersect at a right angle.

This comes from an 8th-grade school math textbook.

Comment: A rectangle is a parallelogram. Do its diagonals intersect at right angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area is $\mathcal{A}=\dfrac{1}{2} 15.6\times 17.2 \,\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\approx 232.372$cm$^2$

[image]

The answer is 116 cm square. The answer would be 232 cm square if there was no halving required.

Comment: Wow! Absolute wow! May I ask how you made the illustration? MSPaint can never be this good.

Comment: Geogebra. It's free (as in "free speech") and you can find it for almost any OS
https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: @amd Now it is :) Anyway the formula for the area doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the area of the [parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) is $\frac{1}{2}d_1 d_2\sin\theta$, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the lengths of the diagonals, and $\theta$ is the angle between the diagonals.

As regards the intersection angle take a look here: [Diagonals of parallelogram intersect at $90^\circ$ if and only if figure is rhombus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355285/diagonals-of-parallelogram-intersect-at-90-circ-if-and-only-if-figure-is-rhom?rq=1)